# Can I reduce the volume of an active buzzer with an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, sound

I connected the Arduino's 5V pin to an active buzzer's positive, and it makes a loud noise. I tried connecting the Arduino's 3.3V pin and yet the active buzzer is making a loud noise. Is there a way to reduce this volume? I am new to electronics and I am playing around with programming and electronics and I don't want to disturb my neighbors with this sound. Should I use some resistor?

If nothing works, I will probably just tape the top of the active buzzer and hope the volume is lower.

I am using the below circuit from a tutorial.

[image: circuit]

Comment: Tape works best, a series resistor is trial and error.

Comment: Both you and Tony are thinking the way I was, at first. Just muffle the thing. There are lots and lots of easy ways to destroy the efficiency of a buzzer. One blast from a shotgun works wonders. Otherwise, just look around the house and you'll find dozens of ways. Nothing electronic needed. But if you are really stuck on something electronic then muffle it with a resistor in series with the buzzer. At some resistor value, you will definitely succeed in muffling it. With a more complex circuit you could current-limit the thing to a predictable value. But that's probably over-kill.